# Firebase keeps throwing OAuth2 client id in server configuration is not found

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to log my Google users into my app using Firebase, but every time I use the below method, I get this error: `An internal error has occured. [ OAuth2 client id in server configuration is not found. ]`.  I have already gotten my client ID key from the developers console, and I am using the web client ID, not Android's in my request token.  Any ideas?

Here is my code:

```
  private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(final GoogleSignInAccount acct) {

        final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(acct.getIdToken(), null);
        mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {


                        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {

                            Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Oops, something went wrong with your login.  Please try again.",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }

                        else{


                            Intent i = new Intent(Login.this, FindOpp.class);
                            startActivity(i);
                        }

                    }
                });
    }
```

Comment: And yes, it is because it is not found. Perhaps, you should double double check. The Firebase Console and Google API console can be a confusing thing to wrap one's head around recently. And just remember, you API Keys is different from your OAuth2 Client IDs

Comment: @Rexford Thank you for your help; my next question, and one I probably should have asked earlier, is what exactly isn't found?  I used my Firebase URL (given in the google-services.json; it looks like this firebaseio.com) to create the web client in the API Console, but what exactly isn't being found?  I used the Client ID given to me by the API console as the ID in my requestToken, so is that not bieng found?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firebase's default config uses the services.json issued from the firebase console (not the cloud console). The Oauth setting is configured automatically when you create the project on the Firebase console so **you should NOT be using any other keys you manually created**.

Having the services.json on your app's module root dir should be everything you need to call the `FirebaseAuth.signInWithCredential` no manual Oauth settings should be required.

Comment: `The Oauth setting is configured automatically when you create the project on the Firebase console` however, this took a good 45 mins or so before my FIrebase console project started appearing on Google developers console with OAuth keys for Web application type. Is this normal?

Comment: weird thing is google documentation says set it in code. https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/google-signin

Answer (score 3):

Here's a discussion which I found on Google Groups which was really helpful: https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=ca#!topic/firebase-talk/d9MHQjAxFBY

I had to whitelist the Web client ID & Web client secret at https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials

Also make sure you are using `requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))` in the code instead of `requestIdToken(<Actual Client ID>)`

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

jirungaray's answer is correct, you should not just generate your own keys in the API console. However, if you are like me and had deleted your keys while messing around, you can fix this situation.

In firebase go to `Authentication` -> `Sign in Method` -> `Google` -> `Web SDK Configuration` and here you can change the key and secret to the values you want.