# Firebase - NodeJS: Domain-Wide Delegation with OAuth2 for Google API

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-api, google-cloud-functions, google-authentication

### Goal:

This Firebase Cloud Function should use [Cloud APIs](https://cloud.google.com/apis/) with **domain-wide delegation** so any user can update *some* G Suite Admin Panel user information when the Firebase DB changes.

### Question:

Which package's method should I use to gain domian-wide delegation for my app.

- [firebase](https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase): `firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider()`
- [googleapis](https://www.npmjs.com/package/googleapis): `google.auth.OAuth2`
- [google-auth-library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-auth-library): `new GoogleAuth()`

### Details:

I'm not connecting the dots regarding the [Google Identity Platform](https://developers.google.com/identity/work/it-apps), and I am stuck [here at this step](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#authorizingrequests).  How does a firebase-hosted nodejs app put together a web and access token for Google API requests?

Firebase projects use Google Cloud Platform projects, so

**I have...**

1. Added to the project a `service account actor` via API/Credentials in the
   GCP-Console
2. Checked the *Enable G Suite Domain-wide Delegation* box
3. Stored the private_key.JSON.
4. Authorized API Clients (in the G Suite Admin Panel) with the Service Account Client ID

**Should I Use...**

**Firebase**: Maybe look into the [whitelisting area of Google OAuth2 settings](https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=ca#!topic/firebase-talk/d9MHQjAxFBY), and/or work with the [services.json I got from firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38594399/1216458).

**Google API** via [googleapis](https://www.npmjs.com/package/googleapis): Even though I'm using `firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider()` to validate the user, maybe use `google.auth.OAuth2` to get domain-wide delegation from GCP (like app or compute engine)

**Google Auth** via [google-auth-library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-auth-library): Again, even though I'm using `firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider()` to validate the user, maybe use `new GoogleAuth()` to get domain-wide delegation from GCP (like app or compute engine)

### Updates

I've learned:

1. Google's npm package `googleapis` is not for clients (browsers). I'm now trying to using it in Firebase Cloud Functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The answer is:

Use `googleapis` for service account authentication with [JWT Service Tokens](https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client#using-jwt-service-tokens).

### Example

The code below is deployed to Firebase Cloud Functions and the logs seem to indicate authentication is successful.

**Firebase Functions Logs**

1. 3:56:35.101 PM authorize Function execution started
2. 3:56:35.620 PM authorize Successfully connected!
3. 3:56:35.668 PM authorize Function execution took 568 ms, finished with status code: 200

**NodeJS Code**

```
// Firebase Admin SDK
const functions = require('firebase-functions')
const admin = require('firebase-admin')
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase)

// Google APIs
const googleapis = require('googleapis')
const drive = googleapis.drive('v3')
const gsuiteAdmin = googleapis.admin('directory_v1')

// Service Account Key - JSON
let privatekey = require("./privatekey.json")

let jwtClient = new googleapis.auth.JWT(
    privatekey.client_email,
    null,
    privatekey.private_key,
    ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user'])

// Firebase Cloud Functions - REST
exports.authorize = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    //authenticate request
    jwtClient.authorize(function (err, tokens) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err)
            return
        } else {
            console.log("Successfully connected!")
        }
        response.send("Successfully connected!")
    })
})
```